# Regex - add a zero after second period

Tags: regex

I have the following example of numbers, and I need to add a zero after the second period (.).

```
1.01.1  
1.01.2  
1.01.3  
1.02.1
```

I would like them to be:

```
1.01.01  
1.01.02  
1.01.03  
1.02.01
```

I have the following so far:

Search:

```
^([^.])(?:[^.]*\.){2}([^.].*)
```

Substitution:

```
0\1
```

but this returns:
01 only.

I need the 1.01. to be captured in a group as well, but now I'm getting confuddled.

Does anyone know what I am missing?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this regex replacement with 2 capture groups:

Search:

```
^(\d+\.\d+)\.([1-9])
```

Replacement:

```
\1.0\2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kUw3jJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d+\.\d+)`: Match 1+ digits + dot followed by 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `([1-9])`: Match digits `1-9` in capture group #2 (this is to avoid putting `0` before already existing `0`)
- **Replacement:** `\1.0\2` inserts `0` just before capture group #2

Answer (score 4):

Using your pattern, you can use 2 capture groups and prepend the second group with a dot in the replacement like for example `\g<1>0\g<2>` or `${1}0${2}` or `$10$2` depending on the language.

```
^((?:[^.]*\.){2})([^.])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `((?:[^.]*\.){2})` Capture **group 1**, match 2 times any char except a dot, then match the dot
- `([^.].*)` Capture **group 2**, match any char except a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5NqWH/1)

A more specific pattern could be matching the digits

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.)(\d)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+\.\d+\.)` Capture **group 1**, match 2 times 1+ digits and a dot
- `(\d)` Capture **group 2**, match a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ebqbmw/1)

For example in JavaScript

```js
const regex = /^(\d+\.\d+\.)(\d)/;
[
  "1.01.1",
  "1.01.2",
  "1.01.3",
  "1.02.1",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$10$2")));
```

Comment: `^((?:[^.]*\.){2})([^.])` is not restricted to numbers e.g. `1.02.a` will be replaced as `1.02.0a`. Also, `1.02.01` will be replaced as `1.02.001`. The second problem is there with `^(\d+\.\d+\.)(\d)` as well.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash There is no problem here, as the OP also does not use an anchor. There is also no restriction mentioned that the character after the dot should not be a zero.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
^([^.]*\.){2}\K
```

Replace with `0`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NzHkH7/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `([^.]*\.){2}` - Negated character 0+ times (greedy) followed by a literal dot, matched twice.
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match.

---

**EDIT:**

Or/And if `\K` meta escape isn't supported, than see if the following does work:

```
^((?:[^.]*\.){2})
```

Replace with `${1}0`. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZXyHY/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group;

  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

    - `Negated character 0+ times (greedy) followed by a literal dot.
    - `){2}` - Close non-capture group and match twice.
  - `)` - Close capture group.

Comment: I didn't know about `\K`. This works great for adding `0` after the 2nd dot but the problem I see is that it is not restricted to numbers e.g. `1.02.a` will be replaced as `1.02.0a`. Another problem that I see is `1.02.01` will be replaced as `1.02.001`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I understand the concern but neither of these were requirements actually. I'd have written a more restrictive pattern if it was more clear from OP. Nonetheless it seemed to have been needed =)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there will be tons of solutions for this, but if this pattern holds (i.e. always the trailing group that is a single digit)... `\.(\d)$` => `\.0\1` would suffice - to merely insert a 0, you don't need to match the whole thing, only just enough context to uniquely identify the places targeted.  In this case, finding all lines ending in a `.` followed by a single digit is enough.